# Contact Form - Not receiving messages

Tags: email, server, email-contact-form

My contact form appears to be working on the front end. No errors or anything that the user is presented with. However, I'm not getting the email off my server. I've tried email addresses on and off my domain, with no success. Any idea what my be causing the issue?

Server: MediaTemple GS
EE: 3.3.0
SITE: creativebyhamilton.com/contact

Mediatemple says there is no issue on their end. They built a test form and were able to send a message to me, which seems that it must be EE.

Here is my code:

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="test@test.com" charset="utf-8"}
        <div class="width-50">
            <label>NAME:</label>
            <input type="text" name="message[]" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="width-50">
            <label>EMAIL:</label>
            <input type="text" name="message[]" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" id="from" name="from" value="test@test.com" />
        </div>
        <div class="width-50">
            <label>PHONE:</label>
            <input type="text" name="message[]" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="width-50">
            <label>COMPANY:</label>
            <input type="text" name="message[]" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="width-100">
            <label>MESSAGE:</label>
            <textarea rows="8" name="message[]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    {/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Comment: is the email module enabled?

Comment: Is the spam module enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question turns out to be a lot simpler than once though. Looks like the main issue was that I didn't have two hidden required fields included:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Email Contact" />
```

For some reason this caused my form to malfunction.

Comment: Correct, both of those fields are required in the POST request, so inclusion with a user-modifiable field or a hidden field, or added via JavaScript on submit, etc., is required. Ref: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#from